# how to get data from web service in mule

Tags: mule

I'm using mule to expose a Web service. I have built a WSDL file and I'm trying to get the text from the message to load into a database but I don't know how to get the text. I'm using a Logger to record my payload as below.

```
INFO  2015-01-20 11:00:54,470 [[ws-mule-cxf].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tra="http://training/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tra:sayHi>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ID>111</ID>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <name>John</name>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <industry>IT</industry>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <REF/>
      </tra:sayHi>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So basically I want to get to text values in ID, Name and industry nodes and map them to a database table. Anyone please let me know how to write the code to get these information? Thanks!

Now I've remove the Database connector part and only put a set payload component to extract data from header and body to check if xpath is working, but it can't.

The configuration XML is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd">
    <db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="localhost" port="3306" user="admin" password="pontiac" database="sqwarepeg" doc:name="MySQL Configuration"/>
    <file:connector name="File" writeToDirectory="C:\Testing" autoDelete="false" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <flow name="sf2dbtestFlow1" doc:name="sf2dbtestFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <cxf:proxy-service port="SF2DBPort" namespace="http://training/" service="SF2DBService" payload="envelope" wsdlLocation="src/test/resources/SF2DB.wsdl" doc:name="CXF"/>
        <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
        <set-payload value="#[xpath('//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*')]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

The error message is:

Execution of the expression "xpath('//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*')" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String

**Update: I added

```
  <mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="soapenv" uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="tra" uri="http://training/"/>
  </mulexml:namespace-manager>
```

in the xml and now it reports another error: 
INFO  2015-01-22 12:22:39,847 [[ws-mule-cxf].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: org.dom4j.tree.DefaultElement@4586a9c5 [Element: http://training/ attributes: []/>]
WARN  2015-01-22 12:22:39,850 [[ws-mule-cxf].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://training/}SF2DBService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unable to convert class org.dom4j.tree.DefaultElement to XMLStreamReader.

Anyone can help?Thank you!
**

Comment: It seems you are using Mule to *consume* a remote web-service, not to *expose* a web-service. Is this right?

Comment: Show the flow to help.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm going to expose a web service, not consume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Database connector](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Database+Connector), take a look at how it works. You will typically use a parametrized query. And use MEL's XPath support. Something like this:

```
<your-inbound-endpoint-here.../>
<set-variable variableName="id" value="#[xpath('//Body/sayHi/ID').text]"/>
<set-variable variableName="name" value="#[xpath('//Body/sayHi/name')]"/>
<set-variable variableName="industry" value="#[xpath('//Body/sayHi/industry')]"/>
<db:template-query name="insert">
  <db:parameterized-query>
    <![CDATA[
      INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE("ID", "NAME", "INDUSTRY") VALUES (:id, :name, :industry);
    ]]>
  </db:parameterized-query>
  <db:in-param name="id" defaultValue="#[id"/>
  <db:in-param name="name" defaultValue="#[name]"/>
  <db:in-param name="industry" defaultValue="#[industry]"/>
</db:template-query>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. But I found I cannot use xpath. My flow has below components: HTTP, CXF, DOM TO XML, SetPayload, DataMapper and Database. In SetPayload component, I write: "#[xpath('soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*')]", but it throws an error saying: Execution of the expression "xpath('soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*')" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String

Comment: I just make my flow a simple version, only includes this: HTTP, CXF, DOM to XML, Variable,Logger. In Variable, I set one variable with "#[xpath('//Body/sayHi/ID').text]", it still reports an error saying "Message payload is of type: String".

Comment: try with a simpler xml and xpath expression, my xpath skills aren't very good and probably I'm not considering the namespaces.

Comment: tries to use <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer /> for avoid Message payload is of type: String

Comment: Hi Julio, that's what I'm using, I'm using <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer /> in my flow. But it still has the same error. My flow includes: TTP, CXF, DOM TO XML, SetPayload, DataMapper and Database

Comment: In order to use the `soapenv` in xpath functions you should declare it in your config file using something like this: `<mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="soap" uri="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"/>
  </mulexml:namespace-manager>`. HTH, Marcos.

Answer (score 0):

Use Http Inbound with SOAP Connector having wsdl details configured.